# iOS - integrate Kal library in xcode 6 errors

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6, kal

I Work with xCode 6 how can i integrate [Kal calendar library](https://github.com/phaibin/Kal) to my project

I follow instructions  on `Integrating Kal into Your Project`

its fine with first steps , but i find problem in integrating to my View

here what I do :
1- I create property of kalViewController and connected to my View

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet KalViewController *kal;

   kal.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Today", @"") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showAndSelectToday)];
  kal.delegate = self;
  dataSource = [[EventKitDataSource alloc] init];
  kal.dataSource = dataSource;


 [self.navigationController pushViewController:_calendarView animated:YES];
```

but i got errors i cant fix it

```
Undeclared selector (showAndSelectToday)

assigning to id <UItableViewdelegate > from incompatible type calendar * const _ strong
```

and some other error

any one can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure why this problem happen

For

> Undeclared selector (showAndSelectToday) Error

the answer add to your class this method

```
- (void)showAndSelectToday
{
    [kal showAndSelectDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

For

> assigning to id  from incompatible type calendar * const _ strong Error

this error appear when I use  `kal.delegate = self;`

in yourclass.h file add UITableViewDelegate

For me its Calendar.h

```
@interface Calendar : UIViewController< UITableViewDelegate >
```